# multiline cells and arrow placement in xymatrix

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, xymatrix

Is there a way to use a multiline environment in a cell of an `\xymatrix`?

I am trying to produce something that looks like this:

```
\[
\left\{ \begin{gathered}\text{text 1}\\
\text{text 2}\\
A=B
\end{gathered}
\right\} \rightleftarrows\left\{ \begin{gathered}\text{some text here}\\
\text{and here}
\end{gathered}
\right\} ,
\]
```

[image],

Only I was hoping to get slightly longer curved arrows. I attempted to use `\xymatrix` but this causes two problems: (1) I get an error message when I try to include multiline environments (e.g. `\gathered`) in the cells, and (2) the arrow ends get positioned above/below the cell content, rather than to its side:

```
\[
\xymatrix{\left\{ \text{text}\right\} \ar@/^{1pc}/[r] & \ar@/^{1pc}/[l]\left\{ \text{more text}\right\} }
\]
```

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What if you try the `Bmatrix` environment in the place of gathered? Also did you really put gathered within `\[  \]`?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to brace the complex objects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  {\begin{Bmatrix}\text{text a}\\\text{text b}\end{Bmatrix}}
  \ar@/^{1pc}/[r] &
  {\begin{Bmatrix}\text{text a}\\\text{text b}\\\text{text c}\end{Bmatrix}}
  \ar@/^{1pc}/[l]
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Coherently with the tag assigned by the user I propose two alternatives; the first with `xy` package and the second with `tikz-cd`.

**FIRST OPTION:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

\xymatrix@C=3pc{{\left\{\begin{aligned}
\text{text a}\\
\text{text b}
\end{aligned}\right\}
} \ar@/^{1.5pc}/[r] & \ar@/^{1.5pc}/[l]{\left\{\begin{aligned}
\text{text a}\\
\text{text b}\\
\text{text c}\\
\end{aligned}\right\}
}}
\end{document}
```

**SECOND OPTION:**
Is there also a chance to get the same result using the package `tikz-cd`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\left\{\begin{array}{lr} \text{text a} \\    \text{text b} \\     \end{array}\right\}   \arrow[r, bend left=15] & \left\{\begin{array}{lr} \text{text a} \\    \text{text b} \\    \text{text c} \\ \end{array}\right\} \arrow[l, bend left=15]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remake of the second example in the @Sebastiano answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.84}
\begin{tikzcd}[bend angle=20]
\left\{\begin{tabular}{lr} 
        text a\\ text b
       \end{tabular}\right\}    \arrow[r, bend left] 
       &    \left\{\begin{tabular}{lr}
                text a\\ text b\\ text c
            \end{tabular}\right\}   \arrow[l, bend left]
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great dear friend :-). Best nice answer.